# How can I use deployment manager to create a new service account and topic and only give it access to that topic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-deployment-manager

I can create a new pub/sub topic in my templates and a new service account.

I can see how to give that service account project wide pub/sub access: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources

Also that example seems to be using a different resource type, this is my template:

```
resources:
  - name: "mytopic"
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics
    #type: pubsub-v1ubsub.v1.topic
    properties:
      topic: "mytopic"
      labels:
        my-lable: mytopic
```

I'm using `gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics` when I switch to `pubsub-v1ubsub.v1.topic` I get:

```
- code: RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
  message: The type [pubsub-v1ubsub.v1.topic] was not found.
```

If I try to add `accessControl` to `gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics` I get:

```
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/mydeployment/resources/mytopic
  message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"statusMessage":"Not
    Found","requestPath":"https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/:setIamPolicy","httpMethod":"POST"}}
```

I want to create a new topic, new service account, and give that service account access to that specific topic *only*.

Is this possible in deployment manager?

This is the full template with accessControl:

```
resources:
  - name: "mytopic"
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics
    #type: pubsub-v1ubsub.v1.topic
    properties:
      topic: "mytopic"
      labels:
        label: "sdfsdfsdf"
    accessControl:
      gcpIamPolicy:
        bindings:
        - role: roles/pubsub.editor
          members:
          - "serviceAccount:zzz@abc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        - role: roles/pubsub.publisher
          members:
          - "serviceAccount:zzz@abc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

### Edit

I think I got this working but now I have a question about dependencies. Do I need to declare the acl resource is dependant on the pub/sub resource? Or is this unnecessary? If I don't include it it works, but I want to confirm that it won't ever fail and try to deploy the acl first or something.

(Google could do with adding a complete example to their docs - it would go a long way to make them much more accessible).

```
resources:
  - name: "mytopic"
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics
    properties:
      topic: "mytopic"

  - name: "mytopic-permissions"
    type: pubsub.v1.topic
    properties:
      topic: "mytopic"
    accessControl:
      gcpIamPolicy:
        bindings:
        - role: roles/pubsub.editor
          members:
          - "serviceAccount:xxxx@abc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        - role: roles/pubsub.publisher
          members:
          - "serviceAccount:xxxx@abc.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    # Do I need this? If I don't have it, deploys still seem to work
    metadata:
      dependsOn:
      - "mytopic"
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the puzzle.   If I read here .. https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources#setting_an_iam_policy_in_your_configuration ... it seems that in the example, they are creating a new topic and then ON THAT TOPIC are giving certain users, certain roles for JUST that topic rather than all topics.  Are you seeing something different or have a different understanding?

Comment: perhaps i misread that then. Where do I see the topic permissions in the UI? Is it visible there or only with gcloud? also when trying that example i get this error ` message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"statusMessage":"Not
    Found","requestPath":"https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/:setIamPolicy","httpMethod":"POST"}}'`

Comment: Go to Cloud Console.  Got to Pub/Sub.  Go to list of topics.   See existing topic.  On right hand row of table, see "3 dots".  Click.  Click View Permissions.

Comment: Can you show your full deployment manager file with your accessControl definition?

Comment: added the full template

Comment: ah i think i see its a new resource. that wasn't to clear to me from the docs. I thought you just added accessControl to a resource definition but you need a totally separate resource just for assigning the acl right?

Comment: also because the acl resource depends on the pubsub resource if I use `"$(ref.mytopic.name)"` to attach the acl resource it will ensure that the pub/sub resource is created first right?

Comment: well this stinks looks like ill need an explicit dependency here because accessconrol just wants the topic name and the ref returns the full url of the topic. Is there a DM macro to parse a "/" separated string and get the leaf?